# Python 2.7 ImportMismatchError caused by stale pycache after basedir rename

Tags: python, caching, python-import, pytest, importerror

I'm trying to understand what happened here so I can prevent it happening again.

I have a Jenkins job running a python program (`pytest` actually). It is using Python 2.7.6 in a virtualenv. At some point, the Jenkins job was renamed, and this causes Jenkins to rename the directory that the job's workspace is stored in. Normally this doesn't cause a problem, and if it does a "Wipe Workspace" tends to sort things out. However for a specific reason this wasn't done and the workspace remained as-is.

After this rename, the python program would refuse to run, issuing a `ImportMismatchError` for a particular python module (`conftest.py`). After some debugging with `pdb` I was able to work out that a cached version of the python module (`conftest.cpython-27-PYTEST.pyc`) was being loaded from a directory called `__pycache__`, and that cached version contained an absolute path that was now invalid. This causes an ImportMismatch error because the absolute path of the cached version does not match the absolute path of the module's source, **but it's still considered a cache hit!**

I understand that this pycache mechanism supersedes the "alongside" `.pyc` cache mechanism of python2 - however there are a few things I don't understand about my situation:

1. Why did `__pycache__` exist given that Jenkins is using Python 2.7.6 and this is something that seems to be supported from 3.2 onwards? Is there any way that Python2 could create this directory? I notice that it has support for creating and reading from the cache, which surprises me - was this back-ported as far as 2.7.6?
2. Why doesn't this mechanism consider the full path of the module in determining whether the cached version is stale or not? In this case, the python module's filename didn't change, but the basedir (path) did. However this did not invalidate the cache and therefore caused the ImportMismatch error. Shouldn't the full path be used as part of the cache key rather than just the filename? With the old `.pyc` alongside mechanism, renaming basedir didn't matter because the relative locations and filenames of the `.py` and `.pyc` files remain constant.

The fix in my case was simple - I just removed the `__pycache__` directory. However it took me two hours to get to this point, mostly as I've not had to deal with this caching mechanism before, so I'd like to understand more about this.

EDIT: here's the entirety of the error message I saw - no mention of `__pycache__` directories or instructions to remove them here unfortunately:

```
+ pytest -s -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv2/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/bcd7891c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 362, in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "/srv2/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/bcd7891c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 680, in pyimport
    raise self.ImportMismatchError(modname, modfile, self)
ImportMismatchError: ('tests.conftest', '/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CI_Job/workspace/tests/conftest.py', local('/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CI_Job_Renamed/workspace/tests/conftest.py'))
ERROR: could not load /srv2/jenkins/jobs/CI_Job_Renamed/workspace/tests/conftest.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It exists because pytest caches its rewritten bytecode there (it needs to rewrite it to provide the verbose assertions with a simple `assert`).

As for only the basename being the key, I'd guess the reason is probably the same as the reason [test modules need unique basenames](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code):

> Note that using this scheme your test files must have unique names, because pytest will import them as top-level modules since there are no packages to derive a full package name from. In other words, the test files in the example above will be imported as test_app and test_view top-level modules by adding tests/ to sys.path.

As for this being the solution for your problem - didn't the error message tell you to remove `__pycache__` directories? It definitely should have.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To answer your question, no, there was no message to remove the `__pycache__` directories. The error was part of a pytest assertion output, was colored red, and had no extra info other than the exception and its message.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the error message in its entirety.

Comment: Oh, looks like it's a much less useful message when it fails while importing the conftest file... There are plans to improve the imports in general though: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2042